# Accessing Dependency Property on Load

Tags: wpf, properties, dependencies

I'm setting up a custom property in one of my user controls as you can see below.

C#

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty RuleType1 = DependencyProperty.Register
   (
      "RuleType1", typeof(int), typeof(EmailNotification), new PropertyMetadata(0)
   );

    public int RuleTypeId
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RuleType1); }
        set { SetValue(RuleType1, value); }
    }
```

XAML

```
<helper:VisitationHours RuleTypeId="2" />
```

This is working great, except, I can't seem to get the RuleTypeId until after the control loads.  It always goes to the default value of 0.  After the control has loaded, I can access whatever value I set.  How can I access this value in the constructor of the control?  Thanks

Comment: that XAML is equivalent to doing: `new VisitationHours() { RuleTypeId = 2 };`. Notice the initializer, where `RuleTypeId` is NOT being sent through the ctor. Try another path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should fix the name of your dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RuleTypeIdProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("RuleTypeId", typeof(int), typeof(EmailNotification), new PropertyMetadata(0)); 

public int RuleTypeId 
{ 
    get { return (int)GetValue(RuleTypeIdProperty); } 
    set { SetValue(RuleTypeIdProperty, value); } 
}
```

Then, if `VisitationHours` is the user control that you want to set the property on, the answer is that you simply can't access the value in the control's contructor. The object is constructed first, then properties are set by WPF.

You might override [OnInitialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.oninitialized.aspx) or attach a handler to the [Initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized.aspx) event for code that must access the property value.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing an event for it.

Comment: Minor correction to your helpful reminder about `OnInitialized`: in some scenarios, that function may not neccessarily appear as an `override`, since (at least, e.g.) `DependencyObject`, `DispatcherObject` and other types don't declare it. Fortunately, the underlying requirement that `XamlObjectWriter` (and other initialization/deserialization infrastructure?) look for is `ISupportInitialize`. For such scenarios, `XamlObjectWriter` will properly call `BeginInit` / `EndInit` whenever that interface (or derived `ISupportInitializeNotification`) is detected on your XAML root object (its `Result`)